# Skype for Ubuntu - pictures sharing broken

Tags: ubuntu, skype

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 x64 and have skype 4.3.0.37.

It is a well-known issue that with this old version all pictures sent by the other party are received as links like this:

```
https://api.asm.skype.com/s/i?0-xxx-a3-somehashkeysecretnumberchars
```

That's OK, I used to use it.

Two days ago by some reason I entered a command `/msnp24` to "improve" group chats. Nothing visible happened and I decided to leave it as is.

But the next day I found that all images sent to me like the link above do not work anymore. I receive `HTTP 404` error and blank screen.

After some experiments I have found that if I rewrite the link to another view it can work. But I do not want to do it for ever incoming link.

```
https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-xxx-a3-somehashkeysecretnumberchars/views/imgpsh_fullsize
```

The **question** is: HOW to return everything back and revert `/msnp24` command?

> I'm a stupid donkey, why the hell I used that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the information provided in the question itself, I was able to create a chrome extension to automatically redirect to a correct URL.

In Order to Run it

1. Put the two files(manifest.json and background.js) with source code in a folder.
2. Go to Chrome Extension Manager (chrome://extensions/) and Check "Developer mode" at the top.
3. Click "Load unpacked extension..." button and choose the folder with files you created above.
4. Login into Skype Web once and then you can close that tab.

The redirection works automatically when the image link is clicked from Skype.

Here is Source Code of the Extension

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Skype- Linux Image Sharing",
"description": "This extension will re-write the image links of skype so that you can see  skype shared images of chrome",
"version": "1.0",
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    var BROKEN_SKYPE_URL = 'https://api.asm.skype.com/s/i?';
    var FIXED_SKYPE_URL = 'https://weu1-api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/IMAGE_ID/views/imgpsh_fullsize'

    var currentUrl = tab.url;
    if (info.status === 'complete' && currentUrl.slice(0, BROKEN_SKYPE_URL.length) == BROKEN_SKYPE_URL) {
        var imageId = currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.indexOf("?")+1,currentUrl.length);
        var finalUrl = FIXED_SKYPE_URL.replace('IMAGE_ID',imageId);
       chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: finalUrl});
    }
});
```

Please read [Create Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for more information.

Comment: Hmm, that's the idea, thanks.. I think I will either do the same for my Firefox (custom script or Greasemonkey), or do a trick with aliasing asm.skype.com to localhost and proxying it with nginx to another url.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue may actually be an issue with skype's servers.  I use an older version of Skype 6.18, on Windows, and also am forced to use the links to receive pictures however recently all links load to blank 404 pages.  It probably doesn't have anything to do with the command issue and is just another way of skype trying to force it's users to upgrade or use newer versions.

UPDATE:1/24
The issue appears to be fixed on windows.  Skype is now giving valid URLs that actually go to the website to load the images.  I think it's been about a week or so now so it's probably fixed for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution I'm afraid, but a clue to the right direction.

/msnp24 is possibly unrelated so you are looking for the wrong answer.

I also use Ubuntu 15.10 (Mate) and the last 24 hours or so both skype image links I have received have been blank like yours. 
I have not entered then msnp24 command though.

To me this looks like the skype api itself may be broken, or the command that creates the link.

Rewriting the link as you showed says "Unauthenticated" for me even though logged into skype and manager on the web.

Comment: I want to believe that /msnp24 is unrelated, but it still does not work.. I don't know what was the reason..

Comment: Myself and Zell are having identical issues, google search shows others in the last few days too. Still doesn't work for me too and I have never done msnp24.
The problem is likely bigger than that and something wrong either with skypes client, servers or anywhere in between.

Comment: Same issue for me too. Updated to latest skype 4.3.0.37 on Ubuntu but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

For now, you can use [Skype Web beta.](https://web.skype.com) Note: Logging in to Skype Web beta will also fix the "Unauthenticated" issue that some people are experiencing with your workaround.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way it works for now...